# Does the property values (or rental price) of a neighborhood/region increase with new residents taking up empty lots or apartments changing residency?

Tags: markets, housing, property

Does research explore the idea that there is an association of house prices in an area or neighborhood with the influx of new residents? That is, if there are empty spaces in a neighborhood, or currently occupied accommodation that has a change of residents; will that affect the prices of the surrounding properties or the rental values?

Is there any substance to the hypothesis to show that the influx, or change of residents affects a 'region' of property prices or sales/rental values? If so, can a 'radial' function of increase be expected?

The other question is whether there is any effect colloquially similar to the 'magical chairs' game in which the latest resident to move into a region of increased popularity will not reap the rewards obtained by the prior residents?